# Prove that sets of events are disjoint (Random Variables)

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

i have a task to prove that sets of some events that are represented by some random variables are disjoint (partitions of $\Omega$), we know that:
$A_n = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)=a_n\}$
and i have to prove that:
$A_n \cap A_m = \emptyset, n\neq m$, is true for
$\{A_n, n \in N_o\}$
I've got something like this:
$$\omega \in A_n \cap A_m \implies\omega \in A_n \land\omega \in A_m \implies X(\omega) = a_n \land X(\omega)= a_m \implies a_n = a_m$$
But the fact $n \neq m$ doesn't tell that $a_n$ and $a_m$ are different. So i think the proof is not complete.
I also think that one event can be represented by only one random variable (i'm not sure). Can you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: The result you are trying to prove is true only when $a_n$'s are distinct.

Comment: The $A_n$'s sets include events that are represented by specific random variable. For example: we flip a coin and the $\Omega$ inlude two outcomes: H and T. And $X(H) = 1$ and $X(T) = 0$. So the event H is contained in set which include all events that are represented by 1 and T is contained in set whcich include all events that are represented by 0. And i think (i'm not sure about it) one event can be represented by only one random variable. So $a_n$'s has to be distinct.